# How does xargs know when a stdin input ends, so that it can start processing it?

Tags: xargs

After reading [Stephen Kitt's reply](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/483675/321811), xargs waits for receiving the stdin input before processing any of the input, such as splitting it into arguments.

How does xargs know when a stdin input ends, so that it can start processing it?

Is `-E` used for specifying the end of a stdin input?

Without it, how does xargs knows when it ends? Is there some timeout?

Comment: How does *any* program know when stdin ends? How does `cat` know to exit when it's reached the tail of the file it's reading, for example? Why is the answer to how `xargs` knows when it's reached the end of *its* stdin any different?

Comment: I don't know. Could you enlighten me?

Comment: That actually helps to clarify the question quite a lot -- that you're not looking for an xargs-specific answer but a generic UNIX-file-operations answer. Stephen is correct -- `read()` returning 0 indicates EOF. From the `read(2)` man page, section RETURN VALUES: *If successful, the number of bytes actually read is returned.  Upon reading end-of-file, zero is returned.  Otherwise, a -1 is returned and the global variable errno is set to indicate the error.*

Comment: ...so, `read()` will either actually read some bytes (and return a positive number with the number of bytes read), or fail to read some bytes (and return a negative number that indicates how/why it failed), or hit end-of-file (and return 0).

Answer (score 13):

To read its input, `xargs` uses the [`read`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html) function (see also [the corresponding Linux manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html)).

`read` reads the next available data from a file descriptor into an area of memory specified by the calling program. As used by `xargs`, `read` waits until either data is available, or an error occurs, or it determines that no more data will ever be available. It returns respectively a positive integer, -1, or 0 in each of these cases.

To determine when it’s finished reading its input (its standard input, or the input specified by the `-a` option), `xargs` looks for the specified end-of-file marker (if the `-E` option was used), or a 0 return value from `read`.

You can see this in action by running

```
printf '%s ' {1..1024} | strace -e read xargs -s 2048 -x
```

Answer (score 1):

> How does xargs know when a stdin input ends, so that it can start processing it?

`xargs` does **not** wait for the end of stdin before starting to process it:

```
$ while date +%H:%S; do sleep 1; done | xargs -n2 echo
16:51 16:52
16:53 16:54
16:55 16:56
16:57 16:58
^C
```

`xargs` knows that the stdin has ended just like any other program, eg. cat(1) or tee(1), by checking the return value of read(2), calling feof(3), etc. `xargs` will also treat a read error on stdin just as an end-of-file.